# Проверка строки в Python

Tags: python-3.x

Хочу проверять введеную строку пользователем мне нужна строка такого вида

```
192.168.4.35 ресепшен
```

То есть нужно получать типа XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX - ip адрес и через пробел все, что угодно. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile('^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}\s.*')
if (p.match(input_string))
    # можно проверить IP адрес на корректность
```

Дополнительная проверка может потребоваться, т.к. регулярка пропустит строку `888.999.444.777 some text`, где нет корректного IP адреса

А вообще лучше

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
try:
   ip = ip_address(input_string.split()[0])
except ValueError:
   print('Incorrect IP address')
except IndexError:
   print('Bad input string')
```

Answer (score 4):

`re.match(r"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s\w*$",line)`